# função para alterar meu .css se a largura da téla for "X"

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3

Olá. estou em fase de aprendizado. Na tentativa de criar um site responsivo.
Preciso de um script .js ou .css. para que quando esta largura no códgo (css) for verdadeira, execute o código. em css.

> (agradeço dês de já qualquer colaboração, conhecimento nunca é d+)

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
}
```

```js
$("#input-search").on("focus", function(){

 $("#input-search").css({"width": "120px"});
  
 }).on("blur", function(){

  $("#input-search").css({"width": "80px"}); 
    
});
```

```html
<li class="search">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="search" placeholder="search" id="input-search" style="width: 80px">
 </div>
 </li>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça mais a sua pergunta. Não ficou clara.

Comment: Ruan seja mais claro na sua pergunta. O que vc quer que mude quando o tamanho da tela for menor? Vc quer trocar uma imagem de lugar? Quer trocar a cor de fundo? Quer trocar o tamanho da fonte? Ou vc quer executar alguma coisa tipo quando for menor executar um **script** que faça o que mais precisamente?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olha, sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, mas eu acho que entendi, vc quer aumentar o tamanho do input, de acordo com a viewport(tela) do cliente.

Se for isso que vc quis dizer, é o seguinte.

o css faz isso pra vc com o popular media querie, já que vc quer dar "`responsividade ao layout`", imagino que vc não tentou, foi colocar o código dentro dele, dessa forma:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {  
  #input-search{
    width: 120px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="search">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="search" placeholder="search" id="input-search" style="width: 80px">
 </div>
 </li>
```

Nesse caso em especifico, como vc está colocando um estilo `in-line de 80px`, a unica forma de sobrescrever do css e com `!important;`, o que já lhe aconselho desde já a **EVITAR AO MAXIMO** usa-lo.

vc também consege controlar o focus do input, usando

```css
#input-search{
  width: 80px
}
  
#input-search:focus{
   width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<li class="search">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="search" placeholder="search" id="input-search">
 </div>
 </li>
```

Evitando o uso de JS nesse caso.

Espero ter lhe ajudado.

Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você não precisa de um script JS pra fazer seu site responsivo, isso é possível apenas com CSS. Uma das melhores formas é utilizar as medias queries do CSS.

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
   body {
     background-color: red;
  }
 }
```

O código acima faz com que a página tenha o fundo vermelho em telas com no minimo 768px.
Esse artigo pode te ajudar [Introdução sobre Media Queries](https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/), dê uma lida.